# Getting UV values per vertex for export

Tags: uv, export, add-on

I'm writing a small exporter for my OpenGL project and I want to get UV values for every vertex from a Mesh object. I can get all the other needed values like the vertex position and normal, but not the UV coords.

Can you help me how to find that?

Thanks!

Comment: [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bmesh.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing scripting with python checkout the documentation

Mesh attributes can be found in the [Bmesh api](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bmesh.html#customdata-access)